# Display Two Dimensional Array in agGrid in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, grid, ag-grid

I was trying to add agGrid in one of my assignment in javascript. Actually I am having a two dimensional array

```
["","data1","data2","data3","data4"],
["data5","data6","data7","",""],
["","data8","data9","",""],
["","data10","data11","",""]
```

I want to display as it is in agGrid. For example

[image]

Also want to show row and column header as they are displayed in above image. Looking for suggestions.

Comment: I tried different demo's available on ag-grid website and by removing/editing columnDefs properties and providing rowData as above(2D array), different grid options mentioned in Grid interface.

Answer (score 2):

ag-Grid expects rowData to be an array of objects, and the field attribute in columnDefs specifies the key by which data should be retrieved for that specific column.

Luckily in JS, besides primitives, everything is pretty much an object. So you can reference array indexes as if they were the string equivalents for objects.

```
var obj = {"0": "First item"};
var first1 = obj[0];
var arr = ["First item"];
var first2 = arr[0];
first1 === first2;
```

Here is a Plunker with an example:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/bdBBcEmd9hRDLn93